# How to finish two instances of activity by finish method

Tags: android, android-activity, instance

I started activity from service by getting gcm message from servers. If I get the message twice, than activity starts two times and if I click on back button and call finish() method than above activity gets closed. And then again click back button no activity happens.

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,
                NotificationAcceptBookingActivity.class);
            notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            notificationIntent.putExtra("bookingId", booking.getBookingId());
            getApplication().startActivity(notificationIntent);ss
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be having more than one instances of an activity alive at a time. However, if you still want it, maybe clearing the activity stack can help you with it. When starting the last activity, use

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

to clear previous activity stack, which will kill 2 (or no matter how many) instances of the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to create new instance of the activity again and again. Before starting the activity just close it if exists.